# tablerows hover with table even/odd styled via CSS

Tags: html, css

even/odd styles set on tablerows but hovering of table rows don't work .
*Try it on : http://jsfiddle.net/w7brN/*

**CSS style :**

```css
#table_even tr:hover { background-color:#fffbae!important; } /* hovering */

#table_even tr:nth-child(odd) td { background-color:#fbfbfb } /*odd*/
#table_even tr:nth-child(even) td { background-color:#e8ecee } /* even*/
```

**HTML Codes:**

```
<table id="table_even" style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <td>##</td>
        <td>##</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>##</td>
        <td>##</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>##</td>
        <td>##</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

how can be solve ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to re-order the CSS and add the `<td>` like so this:

```css
   #table_even tr:nth-child(odd) td {
    background-color: #fbfbfb
} /*odd*/
#table_even tr:nth-child(even) td {
    background-color: #e8ecee
} /* even*/
#table_even tr:hover td {
    background-color: #fffbae;
} /* hovering */
```

Otherwise the nth-child rules will always have precedence over the hover, aswell as you added the background-color to the `<tr>`, not the `<td>`s before.

Comment: Thanks , `Problem SOLVED` , 10min need to accept your answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

In IE there must be declared a  `<!DOCTYPE>` for the `:hover`selector to work on other elements than the `<a>` element.

See http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

Answer (score 0):

Can't we have

```
$(this:even).css & $(this:odd).css
```

will make life easier?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by setting up CSS for even & odd table rows

```
tr {background:#663366;}
tr:hover {background:#FF6633;}
tr.odd {background:#CCCCCC;}

$(document).ready(function () {$("tr:odd").addClass("odd");}):
```

see the example here http://jsfiddle.net/Cpp3p/

Its not working completely in jsfiddle but working in most of browser

cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
#table_even tr:hover { background-color:#fffbae!important; } /* hovering */
```

You are just missing the `td`. Try:

```
#table_even tr:hover td{ background-color:#fffbae!important; } /* hovering */
```